# Formulas: Number of distinct countries with at least 1 region meeting criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

So here's the deal. I have a database, with a list of regions. One row = 1 region. The first part is easy, I need to calculate the number of regions that meet a given criteria:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR((tdata[Col1]/tdata[Col2]<(100-Var1)/100),TRUE)))}
```

Where (tdata[Col1]/tdata[Col2]<(100-Var1)/100) is the criteria I need to meet. I have an IFERROR because the denominator may be 0 occasionnally (because users).

This returns, say 27 regions out of 50 meeting the criteria. Awesome.

Now, the thing is that those regions are within a smaller number of countries. I may have 0, 1 or many regions within a given country meeting the criteria. Now, I need find a formula that will give how many countries have AT LEAST one region meeting the criteria (we don't care if it's more or how many). Say I have 10 countries out of 20 which have at least 1 regions affected. (For each region, its country is listed in [country] in the database).

I have the total number of countries

```
{=SUMPRODUCT((tdata[COUNTRY]<>"")/COUNTIF(tdata[COUNTRY],tdata[COUNTRY] & ""))}
```

However it doesn't seem to be possible to include my previous calculation there, because COUNTIF doesn't want me to do calculations, and also I can't get the error-check in there.

Any idea?

I am tempted to use an UDF for this, since there's already some VBA in the thing. However having the choice with that or a standard function I'd prefer the later unless it's crazy hard.

EDIT:

[Sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ocft05d7k2pf98/Book1.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: I don't get the data, I cannot come up with the values that give anything other than 0 with your first formula, so it is hard to extend it. Can you outline a few rows of data?

Comment: Edited. Both formulas already in the sample & working - first is an array formula. Second one doesn't have to be but i initially used SUMIF for which I needed to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up building a separate table, with 1 country/row. This allowed me to summarize the data per country (which is useful for other indicators), and also greatly simplify the formula workbook-wise as I can just reference those cells.

There comes a point where another table is cheaper & a smarter choice than building everything in formulas.

The list of country & resizing of the table has to be done through VBA, but assuming you have a readily available unique list of countries in a table:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(tdata[reportid],
MATCH(1,(tdata[COUNTRY]=[@countrylist])*
(tdata[GIFD_TACTUALKCAL]/tdata[GIFD_TPLANKCAL]*100<(100-cst_BREAKTRESH)),0))),0,1)
```

Which will give a column that tells me if any sites meets the criteria. Then simply use table sums or

```
=sum(t_summary[COUNTRY])
```